# Automatically changing screen brightness in Fedora 38

Tags: linux, fedora, brightness

When the brightness is not maximum, it automatically changes either increases or decreases randomly. There is no brightnessctl installed, so that's not the problem. This has been happening since Fedora 37 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just solved it: In the settings/Power window there is an "Automatic screen brightness" slider, deactivate it.

I hope it solves your issue[image]

Comment: I do not have such an option for 'Automatic Screen Brightness'.